# f.select if empty sends 'placeholder' as its value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am rails 4.2.5 & ruby 2.3.

We are using f.select in a form as:

```
<%= f.select(:user_id, User.all.collect {|u| [u.name, u.id]}, {include_blank: true}) %>
```

If I don't select anything & submit the form, its sends 'placeholder' as the select's value.

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...", "users"=>{"100"=>{"user_id"=>"placeholder"}}, "commit"=>"Finish"}
```

How to remove this 'placeholder' while submitting the form ?

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What do you want it to be? Have you tried, `{include_blank: true, data: { placeholder: "..."} }` where `...` is what you want?

Comment: @lurker.. yes, I have tried it all. the value goes as 'placeholder'. it should be just empty. What it does is, while updating it automatically converts the value to 0 and takes the value of the first record and updates it, which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there was a code on the JS side which was setting 'placeholder' as the value for select. So when removed it worked properly.

Comment: I suspected there was something outside of Rails doing this. Thanks for confirming.